# Upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 partially failed?

Tags: apt, 16.04, upgrade, dependencies, 16.10

A few days after 16.10 was released (now) I decided to upgrade. Kept receiving errors during the upgrade, until it finally failed. On the CLI running `apt-get upgrade` now gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
20 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up click (0.4.45.1+16.10.20160916-0ubuntu1) ...
Cannot start click due to a conflict with a different locally-installed Python 'click' package.  Remove it using Python packaging tools and try again.
dpkg: error processing package click (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up click-apparmor (0.3.17) ...
Cannot start click due to a conflict with a different locally-installed Python 'click' package.  Remove it using Python packaging tools and try again.
dpkg: error processing package click-apparmor (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up url-dispatcher:amd64 (0.1+16.10.20160816.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Cannot start click due to a conflict with a different locally-installed Python 'click' package.  Remove it using Python packaging tools and try again.
dpkg: error processing package url-dispatcher:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-app-launch:
 ubuntu-app-launch depends on click-apparmor; however:
  Package click-apparmor is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-app-launch (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-system-settings:
 ubuntu-system-settings depends on click | ubuntu-snappy-cli; however:
  Package click is not configured yet.
  Package ubuntu-snappy-cli is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-system-settings (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of url-dispatcher-tools:
 url-dispatcher-tools depends on url-dispatcher (= 0.1+16.10.20160816.1-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package url-dispatcher:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package url-dispatcher-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configurationNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                        of ubuntu-app-launch-tools:
 ubuntu-app-launch-tools depends on ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.9+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package ubuntu-app-launch is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-app-launch-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libunity-scopes1.0:amd64 (1.0.7+16.10.20160921-0ubuntu2) ...
Cannot start click due to a conflict with a different locally-installed Python 'click' package.  Remove it using Python packaging tools and try again.
dpkg: error processing package libunity-scopes1.0:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts:
 ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts depends on ubuntu-system-settings; however:
  Package ubuntu-system-settings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity8:
 unity8 depends on ubuntu-system-settings (>= 0.4); however:
  Package ubuntu-system-settings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity8 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of account-plugin-ubuntuone:
 account-plugin-ubuntuone depends on ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts; however:
  Package ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package account-plugin-ubuntuone (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-plugin-scopes:amd64:
 unity-plugin-scopes:amd64 depends on libunity-scopes1.0; however:
  Package libunity-scopes1.0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity-plugin-scopes:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-greeter-session-broadcast:
 unity-greeter-session-broadcast depends on url-dispatcher-tools; however:
  Package url-dispatcher-tools is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity-greeter-session-broadcast (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity8-desktop-session:
 unity8-desktop-session depends on ubuntu-app-launch; however:
  Package ubuntu-app-launch is not configured yet.
 unity8-desktop-session depends on unity8; however:
  Package unity8 is not configured yet.
 unity8-desktop-session depends on url-dispatcher; however:
  Package url-dispatcher:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity8-desktop-session (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-push-client:
 ubuntu-push-client depends on url-dispatcher; however:
  Package url-dispatcher:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-push-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-scope-click:
 unity-scope-click depends on account-plugin-ubuntuone; however:
  Package account-plugin-ubuntuone is not configured yet.
 unity-scope-click depends on ubuntu-app-launch-tools; however:
  Package ubuntu-app-launch-tools is not configured yet.
 unity-scope-click depends on libunity-scopes1.0; however:
  Package libunity-scopes1.0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity-scope-click (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of account-plugin-facebook:
 account-plugin-facebook depends on libaccount-plugin-facebook | ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts; however:
  Package libaccount-plugin-facebook is not installed.
  Package ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package account-plugin-facebook (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pay-service:
 pay-service depends on ubuntu-push-client (>= 0.68+15.04.20151009); however:
  Package ubuntu-push-client is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pay-service (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity8-common:
 unity8-common depends on unity-plugin-scopes | unity-scopes-impl; however:
  Package unity-plugin-scopes:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package unity-scopes-impl is not installed.
  Package unity-plugin-scopes:amd64 which provides unity-scopes-impl is not configured yet.
 unity8-common depends on unity-scopes-impl-12; however:
  Package unity-scopes-impl-12 is not installed.
  Package unity-plugin-scopes:amd64 which provides unity-scopes-impl-12 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity8-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity8-private:amd64:
 unity8-private:amd64 depends on pay-service; however:
  Package pay-service is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity8-private:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu1) ...
```

.    　.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 click
 click-apparmor
 url-dispatcher:amd64
 ubuntu-app-launch
 ubuntu-system-settings
 url-dispatcher-tools
 ubuntu-app-launch-tools
 libunity-scopes1.0:amd64
 ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts
 unity8
 account-plugin-ubuntuone
 unity-plugin-scopes:amd64
 unity-greeter-session-broadcast
 unity8-desktop-session
 ubuntu-push-client
 unity-scope-click
 account-plugin-facebook
 pay-service
 unity8-common
 unity8-private:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions to getting my system working+upgraded?

Comment: `Cannot start click due to a conflict with a different locally-installed Python 'click' package.  Remove it using Python packaging tools and try again.` . So try `sudo pip uninstall click` then continue with `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Write it as an answer and the bounty is yours!

Comment: In my case, it's not 'pip', it's 'pip3' That's do the tick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the posted output

> Cannot start click due to a conflict with a different locally-installed Python 'click' package. Remove it using Python packaging tools and try again.

The distribution package of `click` has conflict with locally installed `click` module either using `pip3`, `pip`, `easy_install` or just extracted in the file system.

1. Uninstall local module

   ```
   sudo pip3 uninstall click
   ```
2. Then fix and continue pending installation using

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```

If it didn't work with `pip3`, try with `pip`, `easy_install` otherwise search for it manually and delete it.

Comment: user.dz's answer worked for me with one change - it was the python3 click module that was conflicting not python2 - so I did this: `sudo pip3 uninstall click` and then the upgrade completed with no further errors.

Comment: @nickyspag, thank you, I've updated the answer to reflect that as it seems pip3 is exact answer from users feedbacks.

Comment: This solved it for me too. I guess that's a good example of why it's best to avoid `sudo pip install` in the first place.

Comment: I faced the same issue, uninstalled click from python 3 packages but now it throws error saying `File "/usr/bin/click", line 37, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named 'click'
dpkg: error processing package click (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
`
I guess it wants to use the missing package, but installing it again throws conflict issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @brainbreaker. I need some outputs, would you create new question, add the output of `apt-cache policy click python-click python3-click` and `dpkg --audit` . Let me know when you have submitted one.

Comment: @user.dz Here is the link to my question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/874975/errors-while-upgrading-from-16-04-to-16-10

Answer (score 0):

Try to install missing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get reboot
```

After reboot completed, try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: It fails to install the missing. `sudo apt-get install -f` returns the same output as in my question.

Answer (score 0):

To me this fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-click-package
```