# The Package System is Broken after Upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, 17.04

[image]

After upgraded my Ubuntu to 17.04, the package system is broken. When I execute any of the following commands, I got some error.

#### sudo apt-get --fix-broken install

```
$ sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
...
...
ubuntuone-credentials-common unity-plugin-scopes unity-scope-
mediascanner2
  unity-webapps-qml url-dispatcher usermetricsservice vbetool vlc-nox
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  click-apparmor
The following packages will be upgraded:
  click-apparmor
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/10.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 625249 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../click-apparmor_0.3.18_amd64.deb ...
Cannot start click due to a conflict with a different locally-installed Python 'click' package.  Remove it using Python packaging tools and try again.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Cannot start click due to a conflict with a different locally-installed Python 'click' package.  Remove it using Python packaging tools and try again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/click-apparmor_0.3.18_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/click-apparmor_0.3.18_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

#### sudo apt-get full-upgrade

```
$ sudo apt-get full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 click-apparmor : Depends: python3-apparmor-click (= 0.3.17) but 0.3.18 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also have tried the following solutions but they did not work.

- [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) [related to google chrome]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688338/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-related-to-google-chrom)

Anyone know how to fix it without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried the fixes proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874975/errors-while-upgrading-from-16-04-to-16-10) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837354/upgrade-from-16-04-to-16-10-partially-failed?noredirect=1&lq=1) but nothing worked.

Answer (score 8):

I think I found a solution, but a big caveat though: it works, but I can’t explain why.

First, I went to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

Then, I removed the lines pertaining to the packages which caused the problems. In my case, I had to do:

```
sudo rm -r python3-apparmor-click.*
sudo rm -r click-apparmor.*
sudo rm -r click.*
sudo rm -r ubuntu-app-launch.* 
sudo rm -r url-dispatcher-tools.*
sudo rm -r url-dispatcher:amd64.*
sudo rm -r libunity-scopes1.0:amd64
```

After that, I typed:

```
sudo apt purge python3-apparmor-click
sudo apt purge click-apparmor    
sudo apt purge click
sudo apt purge ubuntu-app-launch
sudo apt purge url-dispatcher-tools
sudo apt purge url-dispatcher:amd64
sudo apt purge libunity-scopes1.0
```

After that,

```
sudo apt update
```

And finally,

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

which worked and updated my packages. All the packages problems seem to have disappeared.

Comment: The command `apt purge` returns `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.

Comment: @Casper For every package?

Comment: Yes. It seems so.

Comment: I also had to use aptitude to purge dependencies, apt / apt-get command was not able to do it https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085665/broken-dependencies-after-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-upgrade

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04, this worked for me:

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall click
sudo apt install python3-click-package
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

Not sure why (perhaps pip's click version is different than the one Ubuntu depends on?) but this fixed the issue.

Comment: `pip3 uninstall click` removes the `click` module that was installed via Pip for Python 3 which would likely fix the complaint during the package installation in OP's question as it is the most common installation method for Python modules on Ubuntu outside of Apt. Another options is that they used `easyinstall` or something like `make install`.

Answer (score 5):

First remove python '***click***' package using `pip`:

`pip uninstall click`

If you using ***python3*** :  `pip3 uninstall click`

Then fix the packages by ***apt***:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install -f
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to solve the problem for me (at least I do not get error messages any more):

I did a `sudo apt autoremove` and noted the packages with unmet dependencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bind9-host : Depends: libdns162 (= 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu4) but 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.4 is installed
 dnsutils : Depends: libdns162 (= 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu4) but 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu1.4 is installed
 gnome-software : Depends: gnome-software-common (= 3.22.7-0ubuntu3) but 3.20.1+git20170208.0.a34b091-0ubuntu1 is installed
 gvfs : Depends: gvfs-daemons (>= 1.30.4-0ubuntu1)
 gvfs-backends : Depends: gvfs-daemons (= 1.30.4-0ubuntu1)
 gvfs-daemons : Depends: gvfs-libs (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu2) but 1.30.4-0ubuntu1 is installed
                Depends: gvfs-common (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu2) but 1.30.4-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I went to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and in the 'search' para entered the names following 'Depends: ' and selected 'zesty'. Then I downloaded the .deb files for my hardware.

Next, I moved all the .deb files to /var/cache/apt/archives:

```
sudo mv *.deb /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Lastly I did:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

which executed without errors

HTH

Comment: The command `autoremove` not found. But now I cannot use `apt-get` to install it.

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1: Look for the this foreign click package:

  ```
  sudo updatedb
  locate -ir python.*click
  ```

  Then delete it manually, add the output to the question if you are in doubt.
- Option 2: If you are still at that state mentioned in th e question:

  ```
  Preparing to unpack .../click-apparmor_0.3.18_amd64.deb ...
  Cannot start click due to a conflict with a different 
    locally-installed Python 'click' package.  Remove it 
    using Python packaging tools and try again.
  dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
  ```

  1. Remove the installed package

     ```
     cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
     sudo mv click-apparmor:amd64.prerm click-apparmor:amd64.prerm.backup
     sudo dpkg --force-depends -r  click-apparmor
     ```
  2. Try install the new package using:

     ```
     sudo apt -f install
     ```

     Add the new error if any to the question.