# broken dependencies after Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 18.04, xubuntu

After Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS upgrade, there were several problems: Xubuntu icons missing, broken dependencies, no more network manager...

Do you have any idea why it happened and is there a solution? I cannot update packages anymore with apt-get and aptitude asks me to "try harder".

I cannot believe that so much problems can happen with a stable LTS upgrade. If I can't find a proper solution, I will have to replace Ubuntu with Debian or another Linux distribution.
A few years ago, I switched from Unity interface to Xubuntu to avoid some annoying bugs: https://web.archive.org/web/20140304005924/http://askubuntu.com:80/questions/173146/does-this-webpages-title-appear-on-two-lines-in-your-panel (it looks like my question was removed without any reason which was not nice for an open community Q&A website where closing would be enough and better to keep archives for users)

[image: Ubuntu upgrade problems]
[image: Ubuntu aptitude error]

Comment: @user535733 it looks like my sources.list file and sources.list.d directory is fine, third-party packages are disabled (commented): https://pastebin.com/uLEUhE4F But thanks for your suggestion, any other idea is welcome.

Comment: I found some similar problems and tried this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/904952/the-package-system-is-broken-after-upgraded-to-ubuntu-17-04/905422#905422
I am not sure it was the correct solution to my problem because in the end I had to use aptitude to purge broken dependencies (apt / apt-get command was not able to do it). So maybe the problem could have been fixed by just removing broken dependencies with aptitude. I still have no idea why this broken dependencies problem occurred.

Comment: Had the same problem when upgrading from 16.04.5 to 18.04.1. In `/var/log/dist-upgrade/screenlog.0`, the first failure was that systemd-shim couldn't be removed, because `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service` could not be deleted. I fixed the problem by reverting to my 16.04 backup, then running the command `sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.bak` (from askubuntu.com/a/838673/627717), and finally repeating the upgrade.